# Spring doesn't invoke Hibernate validator for method params validation

Tags: java, hibernate-validator, spring-4

I would like to utilize Hibernate Validator annotations to validate my query parameters that are passed in a request to my service.

```
@GET
@Path("/")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
void searchUsers(@Length(min = 3) @QueryParam("q") String searchTerm, @Range(min = 1, max = Integer.MAX_VALUE) @QueryParam("page") Integer page,
        @Suspended AsyncResponse response);
```

Above is the example of a method. When I place a request with `q` parameter in a request being 2 chars long, my request is not being rejected with 400 code, but instead makes it all the way to the service layer.
Also, if `page` parameter is set to a negative number, validation is not happening.

In my `pom.xml` I have included Hibernate validator dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
   <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Spring version that I am using is `4.1.6`.

Also, in my `applicationContext.xml` I have following beans:

```
<bean id="validator"   class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />
<bean class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationPostProcessor"/>
```

Is there something else I need to configure/enable?

Answer (score -1):

`@Length` constraint consider `null` values as valid. Hence it seems that you either need to set a default value for the `q` or add a `@NotNull` to it.

Comment: That has nothing to do with `@NotNull` constraint as even if I put 2 chars for my `q` parameter, nothing happens

Comment: Well then you should put this stuff into the question. Otherwise it's not obvious what you are doing and what's working for you and what's not. Because as it reads right now is - If there's no q parameter passed @Lenght doesn't work. Which is not apparently the case. The next question would be - do you have a configured `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` in you app ?

Comment: I have modified description of the question with `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` enabled. Still no luck.